# Unable to print newline inside xargs

Tags: bash, echo, newline, xargs

I'm working on some script to help organize some stuff. I have simplified my code down to this from my original:

```
$ echo $(find -type d -maxdepth 5 | grep -E "\./([^/])*/([^/])*/([^/])*/([^/])*"
 | cut -d'/' -f 3 | sort | uniq -d | xargs -I R sh -c 'echo -e "alpha \n"')
(R actually doesn't do anything here but it's used in the original)
```

Particularly, I think something is wrong with my xargs

```
xargs -I R sh -c 'echo -e "alpha \n"'
```

What I would look to see happen is `alpha` to be printed several times, each on a newline. However, my output looks like

```
alpha alpha alpha...
```

I've been scouring around the internet trying to find how to fix this but it's no use. I've just started experimenting with bash, can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the whole thing in `echo $(...)`? That makes you subject to [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Comment: Charles you might just be a lifesaver. I might've been trying to fix the wrong thing all this time

Comment: ... That's not to say that your xargs use is correct, though. I'm not at a computer to test it or any proposed replacement right now, though.

Comment: `sh -c 'echo -e "alpha \n"'` is not going to work since `echo -e` is not POSIX and you are calling a POSIX `sh`. Use `sh -c 'printf "%s \n\n" "alpha"'` instead.

Comment: This seems to be working, thank you. What exactly does %s do?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this syntax? You have not said that. You have written a set of pipes, finally going to xargs not using the actual arguments at all. Do you want to print "alpha" in a newline, as many times as the number of arguments?

Comment: I wanted to run some operations on R defined in xargs and print them out line by line. The manipulation part is easy and works in my code, however when I get the output (ie ```alpha```) it didn't print out line by line

Comment: @LeaGris : Not sure that this explains in this case the observed behaviour. For instance if I try it on `dash`, which is pretty close POSIX, the echo would print something like ` -e alpha` instead. The OP did not state which OS is being used, but on Linux (and similar systems), an alternative would be to use `/bin/echo` explicitly (or `command echo`).

Comment: @user1934428 This is why it is a comment and not an answer. As to why I recommend `printf` rather than `echo` especially when escaping special characters, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64079604/7939871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

---

Just running a command, no `echo`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"
first line
second line
```

Running a command in an unquoted command substitution, as your code is currently written:

```
$ echo $(printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line")
first line second line
```

Running a command in a quoted command substitution:

```
$ echo "$(printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line")"
first line
second line
```

...so: If you don't have a reason for the outer `echo $(...)`, just remove it; and if you *do* have a reason, add quotes.